# How to create "related_name" relation with parent models of "through" model (about related_name inheritance)

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have 4 models including one M2M "through" model enabling to had an index:

```
class TargetShape(models.Model):
    pass
    
class Page(models.Model):
    target_shapes = models.ManyToManyField(TargetShape, through='PageElement', related_name='pages')
    
class PageElement(models.Model):
    target_shape = models.ForeignKey(TargetShape, related_name='page_elements')
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page, related_name='page_elements')
    index = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Order')
    

class WorkingSession(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='working_sessions')
```

I defined another model `Resolution` that enables me to link all of them together in order to create the following `related_name` relations:

```
working_session.resolutions
user.resolutions
target_shape.resolutions
page.resolutions
page_element.resolutions
```

To have it working, I had to declare:

```
class Resolution(models.Model):
    # relations that would be needed from a DRY perspective:
    page_element = models.ForeignKey(PageElement, related_name='resolutions')
    working_session = models.ForeignKey(WorkingSession, related_name='resolutions')
    
    # relations I want to exist to use user.resolutions, target_shape.resolutions, page.resolutions: 
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='resolutions')
    target_shape = models.ForeignKey(TargetShape, related_name='resolutions')
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page, related_name='resolutions')
```

However, that's not very DRY. From a DRY perspective, I should be able to declare  `Resolution` as linking to only `PageElement` and `WorkingSession`, and deduce / inherit the relation with the parent models:

```
class Resolution(models.Model):
    page_element = models.ForeignKey(PageElement, related_name='resolutions')
    working_session = models.ForeignKey(WorkingSession, related_name='resolutions')
```

But in that case, how can I create the following relations:

```
user.resolutions
target_shape.resolutions
page.resolutions
```

without going through:

```
user.working_sessions.resolutions
target_shape.page_elements.resolutions
page.page_elements.resolutions
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out another way: declare in the User, TargetShape and Page models a property that returns a queryset:

```
class Resolution(models.Model):
    page_element = models.ForeignKey(PageElement, related_name='resolutions')
    working_session = models.ForeignKey(WorkingSession, related_name='resolutions')

class PageElement(models.Model):
    target_shape = models.ForeignKey(TargetShape, related_name='page_elements')
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page, related_name='page_elements')
    index = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Order')
    

class WorkingSession(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='working_sessions')



class TargetShape(models.Model):
    @property
    def resolutions(self):
        return Resolution.objects.filter(page_element__target_shape=self) 

    
class Page(models.Model):
    @property
    def resolutions(self):
        return Resolution.objects.filter(page_element__page=self)

    target_shapes = models.ManyToManyField(TargetShape, through='PageElement', related_name='pages')
```

Answer (score 0):

All I can think about is to:

- either declare all fields as I already did
- or declare in the User, TargetShape and Page models a property that respectively returns:

  Resolution.objects.filter(working_session__user=self)
  Resolution.objects.filter(page_element__target_shape=self)
  Resolution.objects.filter(page_element__page=self)

That would surely work, but that's not very elegant ... and not very Django-ish

Does anybody know a more Django-ish way to define this relation?